# Is the following problem NP-complete?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, computational-complexity, np-complete

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a directed graph and let $p_{ji}$ be the minimum path weight from $j$ to $i$; Then I can obviously save the path weights in a matrix $P$ similar to an edge weight matrix;

Now the question is: Find the topological order $\pi: v_1,...,v_d$ such that the sum

$$\min\limits_{\pi \in \Pi}\sum\limits_{j,i \in V(G): \pi(j)<\pi(i)}p_{ji}$$

of all pathes is minimized; Is this problem NP-complete(or NP-hard)?

As an example for a better understanding: If the vertices are given by 1,2,3,4 and 5 and the topological order is just $\pi:1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5$, then the corresponding sum would be:

$$p_{12}+p_{13}+p_{14}+p_{15}+p_{23}+p_{24}+p_{25}+p_{34}+p_{35}+p_{45}$$

and for $\pi:2\ 1\ 3\ 4\ 5$ it would be

$$p_{21}+p_{23}+p_{24}+p_{25}+p_{13}+p_{14}+p_{15}+p_{34}+p_{35}+p_{45}.$$

Now I am looking for a topological order such that such a sum is minimized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is called the linear ordering problem, and is known to be NP-hard.

See, for example, [The Linear Ordering Problem: Instances, Search
Space Analysis and Algorithms](http://iridia.ulb.ac.be/~stuetzle/publications/Lop.pdf)

Comment: This is very interesting, thank you; But obviously, since we are talking about path weights it holds that $p_{ji} \leq p_{jk} \cdot p_{ki}$ whenever $p_{jk},p_{ki}>0$...  Or since we talk about maximizing here (which should be easily transferable) we then have additionally $p_{ji} \geq p_{jk} \cdot p_{ki}$ and also want to maximize the sum- doesnt it make the problem simpler? Maybe? Or is it still NP hard?

Comment: @Johannes You're right, but I still think this is hard. I'll see if I can find a source.

Comment: That would be terrific, if you can find something

Comment: @Johannes The closest thing I found was this paper, which talks about linear ordering problems where the weights satisfy a variant of the triangle inequality. I hope it helps. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X0300444X